# How to set the nofile limit on rsyslog with upstart?

Tags: ubuntu, rsyslog, upstart, ulimit

I'm struggling to work out how to set the open file limit on rsyslog on Ubuntu 14.04.  It uses Upstart, which ignores `limits.conf`, but I'd expect to be able to put

```
limit nofile 16384 16384
```

in `/etc/init/rsyslog.conf` as suggested by [this rsyslog email list post](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/rsyslog/users/18219).  But having done that and run `restart rsyslog`, when I check `/proc/$RYSLOGPID/limits` I can see that the "Max open files" is still 1024 soft, 4096 hard.

My first guess was that the problem is related to the fact that the Upstart script uses `script` tags rather than a simple `exec` to launch `rsyslog`, which does some kind of fancy forking stuff.  However, I tried putting a `ulimit -n` in the `script` section, but to no avail, and I also tried getting rid of the `script` stuff (which exists purely to make sure that the stuff from `/etc/default/rsyslog` is in the environment -- this file was empty apart from setting `RSYSLOGD_OPTIONS` to an empty string, so it was a no-op), also to no avail.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Full upstart script follows:

```
# rsyslog - system logging daemon
#
# rsyslog is an enhanced multi-threaded replacement for the traditional
# syslog daemon, logging messages from applications

description     "system logging daemon"

start on filesystem
stop on runlevel [06]

expect fork
respawn

limit nofile 16384 16384

pre-start script
    /lib/init/apparmor-profile-load usr.sbin.rsyslogd
end script

script
    . /etc/default/rsyslog
    exec rsyslogd $RSYSLOGD_OPTIONS
end script
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David Lang [on the rsyslog mailing list](http://lists.adiscon.net/pipermail/rsyslog/2015-December/041692.html) was able to set me straight on this one.  The problem was that I was using `restart rsyslog`.  This *does not* reload the `rsyslog.conf` upstart file.  If you use `stop rsyslog` and then `start rsyslog`, then the file is read, and the `limit nofile XXXX` option will take effect.